# Rotating a mirrored object by 90 degrees doesn't work as expected

Tags: mirror

See I am trying to make a window for a skyscraper and I almost got everything but one of the bars of the window frame. When I try to rotate it by 90 degrees it behaves weirdly. I want it to be perpendicular to the horizontal bars in the center.

[image: Before]

[image: After]

with that bar selected I hit and release r on my keyboard and type in 90.

Comment: To rotate along some axis, you should hit `R`, type some number and only then release LMB, not before.

Comment: Also make sure that the pivot point is located in the center of this bar so it to rotate in a desired way (hit `Ctrl + ,` to snap pivot point to median point of the selected bar or `Ctrl + .` to individaul origins of it)

Comment: I tried pressing some random buttons and I stumbled upon this option "cliping" for the mirror modifier. Turning it off solved my problem.

Comment: I guess next time I get struck at something like this I could try your solution @MrZak Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that the `Pivot Point` is located in the centre of the selected bar.

To ensure that, hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to make it visible. If it's already, than skip this. You can also see that using this button:

[image]

Then either hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd> (it will snap the pivot point to the median point, that is what you want) or use this menu:

[image: pivot point menu]

In this case it is appropriate to select any of these opitons except `3D Cursor`.

Then select your bar, hit <kbd>R</kbd>, type some number and release left mose button or hit Space.

Option `Clipping` in mirror modifier prevents vertices that are on the mirror plane from being moved from it. You would really like to use it if creating any characters, cars etc, when you wouldn't like vertices on the mirror plane being doubled. See [this](http://www.blender.org/manual/modifiers/generate/mirror.html?highlight=mirror%20modifier#options) for more info.